# Code disappears from Cloud Page after saving or publishing in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, cloudpage

I am building a setup to trigger an automation from the cloud page by following this guide - https://ampscript.xyz/how-tos/how-to-start-status-of-automation-from-marketingcloud-form/

When I try to add the code for form-handler by creating a new Code Resource (Javascript)  and then save or publish in Cloudpages, the code completely disappears and becomes blank. Tried creating a new file and  same is happening

Could anyone help me how to fix this issue and make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be related to the recent issue described here: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000000pbKRQAY

**Problem:**

When saving a code resource with a script tag that uses single quotes
around `'runat=server'` the Content Builder sanitizer will strip the
entire tag block. Example:

```
<script runat='server' language='javascript'>
// this is a script
</script>
```

**Solution:**

Double quotes work fine, example:

```
<script runat="server" language="javascript">
// this is a script
</script>
```

Comment: That is garbage! How would it handle no quotes, eg `<script runat=server>` does that blow up everything too? Sorry, I know its not your fault @LukasLunow - just venting as that is a huge issue and huge impact that seems to be brushed under the rug.

Comment: Thanks for chipping in, @Gortonington - TBH I have not been able to validate this, and did initially only shared the snippet from the known issue page. Apologies for blindly ignoring the "no quotes"-part, which I admit is rubbish :-| I have removed this part from my original answer (and pinged the appropriate people in order to fix the root cause)

Comment: Oh no worries, certainly not on you @lukaslunow and thanks for sharing. I am more furious on the issue happening at all lol.